# Logical concurrency issue with Picasso in custom View

Tags: android, multithreading, picasso

I am creating a custom `View` that displays an image from `Bitmap` loaded by the Picasso framework. To successfully initialize I need both bitmap and the view measure. I am struggling with threading as I cannot predict which thread will finish earlier.

The view starts Picasso with custom `Target` in its constructor. It saves view's width and size in `onSizeChanged`.

```
public class FigureView extends View {

public FigureView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    target = new LoadPictureTarget();
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(R.drawable.amalka).into(target);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    tilesRect.set(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

And the target sets the bitmap and computes resized picture dimensions to fit view's available space:

```
class LoadPictureTarget implements Target {
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        baseBitmap = bitmap;
        origPictureRect = new Rect(0, 0, baseBitmap.getWidth(), baseBitmap.getHeight());
        scaledPictureRect = Misc.centerHorizontally(tilesRect.width(), tilesRect.height(), baseBitmap.getWidth(), baseBitmap.getHeight());            invalidate();
    }

    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }

    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {  }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes `onBitmapLoaded` is called earlier than `onSizeChanged`. But not always, so I cannot move new dimension calculation there either. For now I moved it to `onPaint()` but this is not a solution as I will need to perform intensive bitmap manipulation once I have tghe bitmap AND available space dimensions.

What is proper way for implementation custom view with Picasso when I need view size?